# Initiate new jQuery UI sortable on ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable initiated on page load and that works fine:

```
var regions = $('.region'),
    options = $.extend({}, CvEditor.defaultDragOptions, {
        connectWith: '.region',
        stop: stopHandler, 
    });

regions.sortable(options).disableSelection();
```

I then have a need to reload the page when something else happens on the page and rather than do a full page refresh, I'm reloading the page via Ajax and replacing the sortable element of the DOM with the sortable element in the Ajax response.

At this point, I reinitiate the sortable with the exact same code:

```
var regions = $('.region'),
    options = $.extend({}, CvEditor.defaultDragOptions, {
        connectWith: '.region',
        stop: stopHandler, 
    });

regions.sortable(options).disableSelection();
```

No errors occur at this stage, however I am no longer able to drag my sortable, so it appears the initiation has failed.

Any suggestions why? To be clear, I am not adding elements to the sortable via Ajax, I am replacing the whole sortable container in the DOM.

Comment: are you calling the .sortable() function after the ajax reload?

Comment: I think you may need to post some more code so that we can see execution orders. In theory everything you've said checks out and it should be working.

Comment: @Swires I've put some simplified code up here: http://jsfiddle.net/AYW2n/3/ which shows the stripped down application code. When you drag and drop, the whole sortable element is replaced in the DOM with another and reinitiated. However the new sortable element isn't actually sortable after that second init has run.

Comment: @ggzone Sure am: see jsfiddle.net/AYW2n/3 for example

Comment: i updated the fiddle to a state, where all can take a look at the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/AYW2n/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the final working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AYW2n/8/

The problem is, theres no "init()" call in the ajax callback - this is the solution:

```
$('.testload').load('/echo/html/', { html: snippet() }, function(){
  init();
});
```

Edit: You need to also init the sortable function in your saveHandler function:

```
$(this).replaceWith(snippet()).fadeIn(200, function(){
  init();
});
```

Comment: The init was being called, but not in the right place. Edited to http://jsfiddle.net/AYW2n/14/ to show it in the original structure I set up. Thanks for your help.